Cropped image preview in Sanity rich text editor
I have an Article schema type in Sanity which consists a rich text editor (array of type block) and supports adding inline images.
The rich text editor field is defined like this:
defineField({
  name: 'content',
  title: 'Content',
  description:
    'The main content of the article. You can use rich text formatting',
  type: richTextType.name,
  group: 'content',
}),

The rich text type looks like this:
import { defineField } from 'sanity';
import { ImageIcon } from '@sanity/icons';

export const richTextType = defineField({
  name: 'content',
  title: 'Content',
  description:
    'The main content of the article. You can use rich text formatting',
  type: 'array',
  of: [
  {
    type: 'block',
  },
  {
    title: 'Inline image',
    name: 'inlineImage',
    type: 'image',
    options: {
      hotspot: true,
    },
    icon: ImageIcon,
  },
],
  group: 'content',
});

The options: { hotspot: true }, is set, that means I can crop and select the focus area of the images. This works well with for e.g. the main image of the article, but when I use it in case of inline images, no matter how I crop the image, the whole image will be inserted into the rich text editor.
Since content creators should use this Sanity studio, it can be misleading if I don't show the cropped image in preview.
How can I achieve to show the selected area / cropped image?
